# search value in column

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I want to search if a column contains a value.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pandas as pd

df_init = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1', '2'], 'val':[100, 200]})

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pandasToSparkDF').getOrCreate()


mySchema = StructType([ StructField("id", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("val", IntegerType(), True)])


df = spark.createDataFrame(df_init, schema=mySchema)


if df.filter(df.id == "3"):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

It always prints 'Yes'.

In a pandas dataframe, I would do:

````
if '3' in df_init['id].values:
        print('Yes')
   else:
        print('No')```

but with pyspark I don't know how to handle this.
I tried using 'contains' , 'isin' but still the same.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collect_list` to get all the values in the 'id' column as a list. And then check if your element is in this list:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

if '3' in df.select(F.collect_list('id')).first()[0]:
     print("Yes")
else:
     print('No')
```

OR just check if the count is >=1 after the filter operation:

```
if df.filter(df.id == "3").count() >= 1:
     print("Yes")
else:
     print('No')
```